# Arrival at airport for flights into USA

Tags: usa, airports, dusseldorf

I'm going to fly from Düsseldorf (Germany) to Newark with Lufthansa. I've checked in online, but want to check in baggage at the airport. 
When should I be at Düsseldorf airport?

Comment: When does the airline recommend you be at the airport?

Answer (score 3):

For most international flights at European airports, it is 2 hours, although if you look at the actual print of the eTicket, it will say 90 minutes. [Dusseldorf airport recommends](https://www.dus.com/en/services/gepaeck/check-in) 90mins to 120mins but says to confirm with the airline.

My strategy is to aim to be in the check-in line by 90 minutes before the flight and I have never missed a plane. Most of the time, with the rest of the paperwork ready, I even have time to wait for boarding. In very rare and extreme circumstances, I felt the need to rush to the gate.

This means that plan for time to get to the airport according to typical traffic for that time, plus a small leeway, plus time find your way across the terminal and to the right check-in counter.